# How to improve performance of query with two inner joins?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 3 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `t_event` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `kind` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `short_desc` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `long_desc` varchar(1500) default NULL,
  `location` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  `currency` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `remark_price` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `remark_prerequisite` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `date_start` date NOT NULL,
  `date_end` date default NULL,
  `date_remark` varchar(300) default NULL,
  `time_start` time default NULL,
  `time_end` time default NULL,
  `remark_time` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `leader` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `leader2` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `eve_contact_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `eve_contact_phone` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `eve_contact_email` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `eve_contact_url` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `eve_image_path` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `provider` int(10) default NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_change` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `quality` int(10) default NULL,
  `min_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `max_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `active_for_reservation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cancellation_day1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cancellation_day2` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cancellation_fee1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cancellation_fee2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_event_kind` (`kind`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_event_type` (`type`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_location` (`location`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_currency` (`currency`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_leader` (`leader`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_provider` (`provider`),
  KEY `FK_t_event_t_quality` (`quality`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_currency` FOREIGN KEY (`currency`) REFERENCES `t_currency` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_event_kind` FOREIGN KEY (`kind`) REFERENCES `t_event_kind` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_event_type` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `t_event_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_leader` FOREIGN KEY (`leader`) REFERENCES `t_leader` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location`) REFERENCES `t_location` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_provider` FOREIGN KEY (`provider`) REFERENCES `t_provider` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_event_t_quality` FOREIGN KEY (`quality`) REFERENCES `t_quality` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8432 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `t_location` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `loc_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `loc_detail` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `loc_adress1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `loc_adress2` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `loc_country` int(50) NOT NULL default '1',
  `loc_zip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `loc_loc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `loc_shortdesc` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `loc_contact_name` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `loc_contact_gender` int(10) default NULL,
  `loc_contact_phone` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `loc_contact_email` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `loc_contact_url` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `loc_image_path` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_change` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `provider` int(10) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` USING BTREE (`id`),
  KEY `FK_t_location_t_country` (`loc_country`),
  KEY `FK_t_location_t_gender` (`loc_contact_gender`),
  KEY `FK_t_location_t_provider` (`provider`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_location_t_country` FOREIGN KEY (`loc_country`) REFERENCES `t_country`(`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_location_t_provider` FOREIGN KEY (`provider`) REFERENCES `t_provider` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1287 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `t_dates` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `events_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `events_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `events_end_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IND_id` (`id`),
  KEY `IND_events_id` (`events_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_dates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`events_id`) REFERENCES `t_event` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32048 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

My Query is :

```
SELECT e.*,I.* ,d.*
FROM t_event AS e
INNER JOIN t_location AS I ON   I.id = e.location
INNER JOIN t_dates  AS d ON  d.events_id  = e.id
;
```

this query take 90s to be executed and return = 27727

The PROFILE command show that section "sending data" take almost the time of execution.
The EXPLAIN command is the following :

```
+----+------------+------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys               | key                | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra |
+----+------------+------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE     | I    | ALL | PRIMARY,id                 | NULL               | NULL    | NULL      |  1143 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE     | e    | ref  | PRIMARY,FK_t_event_t_location | FK_t_event_t_location | 4       | wu_db.I.id |     4 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE     | d    | ref  | IND_events_id               | IND_events_id       | 4       | wu_db.e.id |     3 |       |
+----+------------+------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

My point of view is that the big number of column is responsible of this slowdown but even when I write  "SELECT e.id, I.events_id, d.id" it still take 16 s.

I think that I have to rewrite the query with LIMIT and OFFSET clause, what do you think?

number of records for each tables :

- t_event = 7991
- t_location = 1086
- t_dates = 27727

Comment: Depending on the size of your database, the inner join is going to take a long time.  Especially since you do it twice.  Even with a LIMIT and OFFSET, it won't speed that up.  How many records are in these tables?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for posting a detailed question that included your own efforts to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, MySQL can only filter records using *one* index from each table in a query.

That is, whilst your `t_event` table has indexes defined on both `id` and `location`, only one of those indexes can be used to satisfy your query.  You can see this in your `EXPLAIN` output, which indicates that both the `PRIMARY` and `FK_t_event_t_location` keys were identified as possibly useful (with the latter actually selected for use).

Therefore, your join with `t_dates`, which involves a test on the `id` column, is being fulfilled with a table scan rather than an index lookup.  Again, you can see this from the first row in the `EXPLAIN` output which shows `type = ALL` (table scan) and `key = NULL` (no index being used).

You should create a composite index on `(id, location)` for your `t_event` table:

```
ALTER TABLE t_event ADD INDEX (id, location);
```

Comment: Hi eggyal, Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I have added a composite index on (id, location) for t_event table but the query still take  90 s to be executed. And I still obtain the same output for EXPLAIN command. I am convinced that the solution is in a composite index, may be we didn't make the right composite index

Comment: Hi Kirk Backus, the number of records for each tables :

    t_event = 7991
    t_location = 1086
    t_dates = 27727

Comment: Hi eggyal, Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I have added a composite index on (id, location) for t_event table but the query still take 90 s to be executed. And I still obtain the same output for EXPLAIN command. I am convinced that the solution is in a composite index, may be we didn't make the right composite index

Answer (score 0):

> My point of view is that the big number of column is responsible of this slowdown but even > when I write "SELECT e.id, I.events_id, d.id" it still take 16 s.
>
> I think that I have to rewrite the query with LIMIT and OFFSET clause, what do you think?

I think you're right.

If you could speed up the `JOIN` by a factor of **infinite**, you would decrease to zero the "select" phase, and would leave the "sending data" part untouched - that's the other 74 seconds.

In other words, an *infinite effort* of query optimization would give you an advantage of 16 seconds out of 90 - around 18% overall.

If this is a batch query, then the time isn't so important; if it is not, as I believe, then I think it's really unlikely that someone is going to want a display, or even a synopsis, of some 27 thousands items.

Apart from a "paging" approach, or if a paging approach turned out not to be practical, or even *in addition* to a paging approach, you could see whether your application could use some kind of "filter" query (date ranges, location ranges).

So I'd study what `WHERE` conditions might be used to make that selection leaner.

If it is a Web application, you could `SELECT` only the IDs (the query you already tried, the one taking only 16 s; and with a WHERE, maybe even less), or as few columns as possible. Let's imagine that now you're displaying a very long page with lots of "forms" holding all the information, e.g.

```
...
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ...... Notes: ....  |
| Leader: .... Cost: ....                |
  ... and so on and so forth ...
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ...... Notes: ....  |
  ... and so on and so forth ...
+----------------------------------------+
...
```

You could, instead, display only a very basic, minimal set of information, corresponding to the columns you have fetched:

```
...
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
...
```

At this point, the user will be able to quickly browse the list, but almost certainly won't open *all* those forms, but only two or three. When the user clicks on `OPEN`, a jQuery function could issue a very fast AJAX call to the server, supplying the data with the IDs; then three separate queries would retrieve all the relevant data in milliseconds.

The data would be `json_encode()`d and sent back to jQuery, and the form would "open" displaying all the information in "accordion" fashion:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......       <CLOSE>|
| large form with all the information
| ...
| ...
+----------------------------------------+
| Date: ....  Place: ......        <OPEN>|
```

This way you would not need to *immediately* retrieve all the columns, especially those largish columns such as `short_desc` and `long_desc`, which can reach two whole Kb between them, and yet the user would experience very fast response.

Comment: Hi Iserni for the response, could you please explain me more what did mean this sentence " Or if it is a Web application, you could SELECT only the IDs, and fill the other information using AJAX (particularly short_desc and long_desc).". And more especially "particularly short_desc and long_desc". Best regards

Comment: Done, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand how you proceed